# Linear Regression - Does the below implementation of ridge regression finding coefficient term using gradient method is correct?

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

Implemented ridge regression formula using gradient method. Below one executes in repeatedly for specified iteration. Is that below one correct since i am not able to find correct implementation anywhere.Thanks.

```
#ridge regression

lambda = 1

#self.apha is learning rate
    self.theta-=  (lambda * self.theta) + self.alpha/self.n_samples * 
    self.X.T @ (predictions - self.y)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from this post https://towardsdatascience.com/l1-and-l2-regularization-methods-ce25e7fc831c .
The written code is correct.